# How to Dynamically populate options for javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sweetalert

I have an application where javascript and html is largely separated. I am trying to write something with javascript or jquery that will pull in all of the data-attributes from an html element and put those into options for a javascript function, Dynamically. There are many options, every time this script is mentioned, not all will be used.

First an example, then ill show how I am doing it (semi-successfully) afterward.

**HTML:**

```
<button data-behavior="sweetalert" data-title="Alert Title" data-text="Lorem ipsum dolar..." data-showCancelButton="true">Click Me</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
sweetAlert({
    title: "Alert Title",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolar...",
    showCancelButton: true,
});
```

Straight forward right? Ok, now lets get fancy and populate it dynamcially. So what I want is to be able to find an option in the sweetAlert api and then be able to simply attach it to my html element with a `data-attribute`. This way front end people can add quick html, without script tags all over the place.

This is what I have done so far that actually does work and gives me the appropriate result, except with options that require non-strings (such as booleans).

```
$('[data-behavior="sweetalert"]').click(function() {
    attributes = $(this).data();
    delete attributes["behavior"];
    sweetAlert($.each(attributes, function(key, value) {
        key + ": " + value + ', '
    }));
});
```

So this function works and pulls in the title and the description correctly. However, it does not pull in the boolean options correctly.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can improve this so that I would be able to set boolean options (at the very least) and secondarily integer options?

*Surely someone out there has done this type of thing before...* Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean it "does not pull in the boolean options correctly"? [`.data()` seems to do it correctly to me](https://jsfiddle.net/25xj6Ltv/). If you mean that it isn't camelCased then write your data attributes using `-` and it will camel case it for you. `data-show-cancel-button` -> `showCancelButton`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery `.data()` function automatically converts "true" to `true`. So this should work:

```
$('[data-behavior="sweetalert"]').click(function() {
    attributes = $(this).data();
    delete attributes["behavior"];
    sweetAlert(attributes);
});
```

`data()` also automatically converts integers, so you should be set on that front as well.

Edit to add comment from OP: data attributes are converted to camel case.  So in order for `data()` to produce an attribute called `showCancelButton` you should write it as `data-show-cancel-button` on the element.

Comment: Won't it convert `data-title="true"` to `boolean` ? Just a doubt!

Comment: Pro-tip: you can also remove that attribute using `delete attributes.behavior`. You only need to use string accessing when the string is not a valid identifier. @RayonDabre It will convert it to `true`. That's exactly what he said.

Comment: @MikeC Sir, that will not be the expected case then. OP must be expecting `string` there..

Comment: Yes @RayonDabre if you tried to title it "true" you may run into an issue, I don't know how sweetalert would handle a boolean there.  If you need to get the raw value (without auto casting) you have to use `$(this).attr('data-title')`

Comment: @Jeff, Yeah.. __If__ condition will come into picture I guess..Not sure how other widgets which uses the `data-*` attributes initialization deal with this..

Comment: @RayonDabre But what are the odds that you want your title to be "true"? Besides, if he was really, really worried about it, he could just do `attributes.title = attributes.title.toString()` before passing it to `sweetAlert`.

Comment: @RayonDabre Mike is right, if you want to be explicit about how an attribute should be cast you just need to do it manually.

Comment: Yes, But In current example, All the `data_*` attributes are blindly used in the `sweetAlert` initialization. That could raise an issue if certain values are suppose to be string and `data()` will cast them to `Number` or `Boolean`

Comment: Ok, yes this does seem to correct the true/false items. Crazy how simple the solution is. Ill mark it as the correct answer. However, now I am running into a related problem. The sweet alert api uses camel case for options such as showCancelButton: true. But it seems that `.data()` makes them all lowercase. But it works if you do `data-Show-Cancel-Button`, then it converts it into appropriate camelcase. Just a little "gotcha" for anyone wondering.

Comment: Good addition @jacurtis, I added that to my answer for future readers.